# git and xcode - untracked files

Tags: gitignore, git-status

I started work on a new project and found I had the following when I launched Xcode:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

modified: <project>.xccheckout
```

and

```
Untracked files: 

<project>/xcshareddata/
```

I then edited `.gitignore` to ignore `.xccheckout` and checked the status. It now read as follows:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

modified: .gitignore
modified: <project>.xccheckout
```

i.e. the Untracked files mentioned previously were no longer being output by git. I've tried this several times and it's completely reproducible - but completely inexplicable.

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind about [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is that files that are already tracked/added aren't affected by it. And it looks like your `<project>.xccheckout` is already git-versioned.

To trick git into assuming that thist file is committed but remain unchanged you can do:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/<project>.xccheckout
```

To reverse:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/<project>.xccheckout
```

As for `<project>/xcshareddata/`, I assume there are `.xccheckout` files in there that are untracked by git. Hence, after your `.gitignore` is introduced, git ignores all of them.